# Two different functionalites in one Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I have two working Jenkins plugins (one implements RootAction and one extends ListViewColumn). Now I would like to install one single plugin and have both functionalites showing in the same instance and later having some connection between them two.

At the current stage only the firstly created plugin in this project folder shows while the other only sits in the project, invisible, when running the plugin in debug mode. I looked at the [extra-columns-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extra+Columns+Plugin) to see where I should put all the files in the project folder (all though they extend to the same class which I don't) but without success..

Is there something I have to specifiy somewhere so that Jenkins detects multiple extension points which in turn will show both functionalites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the plugin which contained both extension points in a real Jenkins instance (not debug mode) gave me an error on the one that was not showing. I then realized that I had two folders in the wrong order in this project so that the .jelly files couldn't be found. Now both functionalites show when the single plugin is installed, both in debug mode and in a real instance, without having to specify any relation or dependency. Noobish mistake...